# Facebook API: What is the Max length of 'message' on wall?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

I've scoured the Facebook documentation and I can't find the maximum length that can be passed to the Facebook API?

If I pass a large value to the API using AJAX and using the PHP SDK, I'm getting neither and error or success message. (and no message on the wall).

I'd like to restrict the user to the correct length to avoid any problems.

Thanks for your assistance,

Luke

Comment: I guess the [`feed` connection](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/) accept up to 500 characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the message is a status update (that is, you're not including an attachment or an action link), it can contain up to 420 characters. Otherwise, if the post contains an attachment or action link, the message can contain up to 10,000 characters.

Answer (score 2):

According to this **[Mashable article](http://mashable.com/2011/11/30/facebook-status-63206-characters/#8qfsTjMMhSq8)** the max length of Facebook status updates is **63,206 characters**...

[image]