# What is maximum message length for Facebook wall post

Tags: facebook-graph-api, sharing, facebook-wall

I am sharing message from my site on facebook wall post. What should be the max length of that message ?

Answer (score 6):

It seems it is 63206 chars long.

http://www.zdnet.com/blog/facebook/facebook-increases-status-update-character-limit-to-63206/5754

Related to Graph-API, here are the limits known:

**Name:**

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#100) name parameter cannot be longer than 1000 characters.", 
    "type": "OAuthException", 
    "code": 100
  }
}
```

**Caption:**

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#100) caption parameter cannot be longer than 1000 characters.", 
    "type": "OAuthException", 
    "code": 100
  }
}
```

**Link:**

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#100) link too long", 
    "type": "OAuthException", 
    "code": 100
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If the message is a status update (that is, you're not including an attachment or an action link), it can contain up to 420 characters. Otherwise, if the post contains an attachment or action link, the message can contain up to 10,000 characters.

[Facebook API: What is the Max length of 'message' on wall?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7141142/facebook-api-what-is-the-max-length-of-message-on-wall)